# Bernoulli trials using a condition in a vectorized operation

Tags: python, array, numpy, statistics, vectorization

I was wondering how to vectorize the following code instead of using the for-loop and still be able to check for a condition.

```
# n is a numpy array which keeps the 'number of trials' parameter for the binomial distribution
# p is a numpy array which keeps the 'probability of success' parameter for the binomial distribution
# baf is a numpy array that will keep the results from the np.random.binomial() function

baf = np.repeat(np.nan, n.size)
for index, value in enumerate(n):
    if value >= 30:
        baf[index] = np.random.binomial(value, p[index]) / value
```

My own vectorized solution is:

```
baf = np.repeat(np.nan, n.size)
indices = np.where(n >= 30)[0] 
baf[indices] = np.random.binomial(n[indices], p[indices]).astype(float) / n[indices]
```

However, I was wondering whether there are other more efficient solutions?

Comment: `.astype(float)` can be dropped if division is true. (That is, by default in Python 3, or in Python 2 if you have `from __future__ import division`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize all entries of an array to the same value, `np.repeat` is probably not the fastest option, and definitely not what most people would expect to find. The more proper way would probably be:

```
baf = np.full((n.size,), fill_value=np.nan)
```

And for cases like this it is typically faster to use a boolean mask for indexing, skipping the call to `np.where` to extract the numerical indices. This should do the same faster:

```
mask = n >= 30
baf[mask] = np.random.binomial(n[mask], p[mask]).astype(float) / n[mask]
```